# Changing a Unix server date with a scheduled job

Tags: date, unix, scheduled-tasks, cron

I am looking for a way to schedule a set of commands on a unix server. The **server time is in UTC**. I essentially want to perform the below steps automatically every Wednesday at 4pm UK time:

- Change the server date to the next time it is UK midnight (to avoid timezone change issues)
- Restart the tomcat server
- If tomcat is running, run a jar
- Change the server date to the correct present UTC time
- Restart the tomcat server
- If tomcat is running, we are done

The below commands are what I currently run manually:

```
date -s "Thu Feb 09 00:01:00 UTC 2017" (represents the next day at 1 minute past midnight)
service tomcat restart
sudo -u tomcat java -jar Test.jar -type "Major" -status "Active"
date -s "<the current UTC time>"
service tomcat restart
```

I understand we can use cron to schedule the running of a script, but unsure how to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called called **unix-server-date.sh** and save it in /opt for example. The script will have this content:

```
#!/bin/bash
date -s "Thu Feb 09 00:01:00 UTC 2017" (represents the next day at 1 minute past midnight)
service tomcat restart
sudo -u tomcat java -jar Test.jar -type "Major" -status "Active"
date -s "<the current UTC time>"
service tomcat restart
```

Make the script executable:

```
chmod +x /opt/unix-server-date.sh
```

Then issue **crontab -e** to edit the crontab entries and add an entry like:

```
00 16 * * 3 /opt/unix-server-date.sh
```

Depending on your editor, after you have added the crontab entry please save the file and the crontab will be automatically installed.

That would be the basics!

If you run those commands from a specific user account you should add the cronjob to that user's crontab. Change **crontab -e** to **crontab -e -u user**

Comment: Thanks for the help for crontab! On the script, is there a way to have it intelligently know what the next day at 1 minute past midnight will be? I will set the cronjob for the same day every week, but it will need to accommodate for daylight saving changes too.

Comment: Why don't use NTP or Chronyd so the time will be automatically adjusted on the server?

Comment: Because we only want to change the date when we want to execute the JAR, which is when we need to move the server time forward, before putting it back again to the correct time in UTC. The JAR has to be executed at 1 minute past midnight, but we only run the JAR during working hours so someone can monitor it.